# mahout top score words, and false positives

Tags: mahout

I've set up mahout to provide some classification for news articles, so i can extract only those news articles which are of interest.

I've gone through an manually trained the titles of these news articles, done approximately 80,000 (both articles i want and don't want)

I have written an app which outputs the top words and their scores, and it seems certain keywords are creeping high up on the top words.

Some of the so called top words are false positives, - they are only top because every title page has them.

such as 'stratford herald' (which is a name of the newspaper) - is there anyway to remove them once a model is already created?

There are about 20 top words which i would like to simply get rid off (or get mahout to ignore when providing best labels), but i don't want this to be an exercise on input (i.e. filtering those names id like to exclude on training input), i'd prefer to post remove as I've already spent a lot of time manually training.

- home: 1067
- dorset: 1493
- details: 908
- back: 867
- poole: 1651
- set: 819
- help: 743
- get: 812
- bournemouth: 14728
- new: 2661
- avon: 2684
- local: 3092
- cherries: 1244
- police: 1011
- over: 1813
- echo: 6526
- null: 79983
- after: 2292
- stratford: 2657
- school: 1395
- jobs: 881
- job: 6982
- car: 772
- herald: 2817
- nurse: 1174
- man: 1335
- manager: 1071
- day: 759
- time: 764
- council: 824
- upon: 2676
  Number of labels: 2
  Number of documents in training set: 79983
  Top 75 words for label negative_article
- stratford: 10748.598348617554
- herald: 7579.555884361267
- avon: 7484.692479610443
- upon: 7476.3635239601135
- local: 7426.4039397239685
- after: 3837.6605548858643
- man: 3512.4373264312744
- police: 2586.899124145508
- over: 1537.557123184204
- woman: 1434.1630334854126
  Top 75 words for label other
- bournemouth: 39076.86379265785
- job: 24028.39960718155
- echo: 22974.801107406616
- new: 10888.526140213013
- stratford: 8045.635549545288
- poole: 7493.278381347656
- over: 7077.8266887664795
- school: 7011.863867282867
- local: 7004.647378444672
- dorset: 6961.040742397308

Comment: You're quite explicit about what you want, so I'm not going to tell you "don't do it" as an answer. However, note that this will corrupt your model, potentially quite severely. You'll be left with a model that is entirely missing words that are both common and highly relevant to the topic/sentiment of a news article, e.g. "police", "nurse", "school", "help". It sounds like the proper way to handle the situation you describe is to filter out the parts of the input that are "headers" (not based on the words, but based on the document structure). (As you mention, this would mean re-training.)

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply

I thought this may be the case - however if only things like 'bournemouth' or 'stafford' are removed, then the model should remain consistent i think, as if they do appear as a 'positive positive' then hopefully the other words in the title will be used to correctly identify,

When you say the structure of the document, i already thought of this, the main issue is that all the news sites use different delimiters in their titles, and its all under the title tag, so filtering out won't be generic. =(

Comment: eg [title]Some new story - Stafford Herald[/title] - when i access the title tag, it contains the actual title, and the news paper name appended with some delimiter =(

Comment: I may have misread your question. If all the words you want to remove are words like "Stratford", "Bournemouth" and "Herald" then it's not going to matter much. I thought you were proposing to remove words like "help" and "nurse". Still, consider that this is not universal -- not all newspaper names consist of obscure words. "The Sun" is a tabloid, but "sun" in an actual headline is probably strongly indicative of a positive story about the weather. If you had data from The Sun you'd probably want to filter out only "- The Sun" as a suffix.